# Scroll a image on a set path with javascript HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a background image, like a map, with a road. The road is not straight, it also has some curves on it.I want to do something similar with the attached link, but like I said, on a road that is not straight. I tried some existing scripts, like jQuery Scroll Path, but this is based on background rotation around the object that you want to scroll, and I don't need it this way. If you can give me some suggestions on how to make it happen, I will appreciate.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be something for you

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/new-plugin-jquery-crspline-animates-elements-smoothly-along-arbitrary-length-sequences-of-waypoints-in-2d

there you set positions and the element will follow

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Breezer, I've haven't saw this library until now. Seems interesting, and it might just do the trick!